# Running multiple celery chains are getting mixed

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

We have started one celery worker reading from Rabbitmq (one queue):
`celery -A tasks worker -c 1` (one process)

We send to RabbitMq 2 chains (3 tasks in each chain):
`chain(*tasks_to_chain1).apply_async()` (let's call it C1 and its tasks C1.1, C1.2, C1.3)
`chain(*tasks_to_chain2).apply_async()` (let's call it C2 and its tasks C2.1, C2.2, C2.3)

We expected the tasks to be run in this order:  C1.1, C1.2, C1.3, C2.1, C2.2, C2.3.
However we are seeing this instead:  C1.1, C2.1, C1.2, C2.2, C1.3, C2.3.

We don't get why. Can someone shed some light on what's happening?

Many thanks,

Edit: more generally speaking we observe that chain 2 starts before chain 1 ends.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to full code it is not possible to test, but a plausible explanation is that your asynchronous sender just happens to do that. I would also assume the order is not deterministic. You will likely get somewhat different results if you keep repeating this.

When you execute `apply_async()`, an asynchronous task is created that will (probably, not sure without seeing code) start submitting those tasks to the queue, but as the call is not blocking, your main program immediately proceeds to the second `apply_async()` that creates another background task to submit things to the queue.

These two background tasks will run in the background handled by a scheduler. What you now see in your output is that each task submits one item to the queue but then passes control to the other task, which again submits one and then hands back control.

If you do not want this to happen asynchronously, use apply instead of apply_async. This is a blocking call, and your main program execution does not proceed until the first three tasks have been submitted.  With asynchronous you can never be sure of the exact order of execution between tasks. You will know C1.1 will happen before C1.2 but you cannot guarantee how C1 and C2 tasks are interleaved.